# Help w/ associative array merge

Tags: php, arrays, json

greetings.  i'm trying to create a new array w/ all the fixins from an old array.  my feed looks like:

{"id":"75",
"team_name":"team1",
"home_team_name":"team1",
"image":"team1_HOME.png",
"final_score":"37"},
{"id":"75",
"team_name":"team2",
"home_team_name":"team1",
"image":"team2_AWAY.png",
"final_score":"10"},

so each game has to records associated with it, how can i pick and choose data to place in a new array so i get an array like:

{"id":"75",
"team_name":"team1",
"home_team_name":"team2",
"image_home":"team1_HOME.png",
"image_visitor":"team2_AWAY.png",
"final_score_1":"37",
"final_score_2":"99"},

i've tried using next() and continue; to no avail...

__
* update:

they keep two records for each game, one for each score and some 'meta' about the team.  i need to grab both records by matching id and run some logic on it to find out who the home team is, who the visiting team is, home score, visiting score.  loop through and list.

is the best method creating a new array if the ids match?

or is there a way that i can just check the next records id while i'm in the current record for a match, if so run some logic?

thanks,

Comment: Where did final_score_2 come from? I'm a bit confused at what you're trying to do.

Comment: would be nice if id's were unique then for each element in the array you basically just check for the id number.

Comment: @aaron hathaway - thats part of the new array i'm trying to create.  they keep their data for each game as two sep records, really i'm just trying to create a new one that concatenates all the info from the orig two records w/ the same id into one easily loopable one.

Comment: @kyj112 - right!  i figure making my own array is the best approach to combining the two.  let me know if my logic is flawed tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i ended up not merging the two items into one and just traversing by two and looking back at the prev() record like so:

```
for( $i = 1; $i < count( $json_output ); $i += 2 ) :                    
    $current = $json_output[$i];
    $last = $json_output[$i-1];
    $item_from_last_array = $last['item_name'];
    $item_from_this_array = $current['item_name'];
endfor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try array_push, it will add to the end of an array. Also, "75" should be 75 since you're usually handling numerals as ID's.

It's good practice but not required.

Comment: i'll look into that... unfortunately i have zero control over the feeds i'm grabbing.